# Cannot get datasource in static Java method

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to access Oracle datasource from CDI bean.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Named("ParentIDNameResolveController")
@ViewScoped
public class ParentIDNameResolve implements Serializable
{

    // Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private static DataSource ds;


    // Get the ID if the parent

    public static int ParentId(int chieldId) throws SQLException
    {

        int ParentId = 0;

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        try
        {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COMPONENTID, FKCOMPONENTID, COMPONENTSTATSID from COMPONENT where COMPONENTID = ?");
            ps.setLong(1, chieldId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                ParentId = rs.getInt("FKCOMPONENTID");
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (ps != null)
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }


        return ParentId;
    }

    // Get Parent Name

    public static String ParentName(int ParentId) throws SQLException
    {

        String ParentName = null;

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        try
        {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COMPONENTSTATSID, NAME from COMPONENTSTATS where COMPONENTSTATSID = ?");
            ps.setLong(1, ParentId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                ParentName = rs.getString("NAME");
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (ps != null)
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }


        return ParentName;
    }



}
```

Unfortunately when I reference datasource from static Java method I get this error:

```
Can't get data source
```

I'm not sure is it possible to access datasource from static Java method. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried not using `static` attribute nor methods at all? Also, you can't use the `@ViewScoped` annotation on a CDI bean, that annotation belongs only to JSF managed beans (at least not if you use it from `javax.faces.bean` package).

Comment: What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Why in the first place you want/need to set the attribute as `static`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not sure that your container will inject anything with adnotation `@Resource` to a static field or a static method. Try to rethink your class and maybe make it as `@ApplicationScoped` then you will also have only one instance per application.

Here are little changes to your class:

```
@Named("ParentIDNameResolveController")
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped  // not from javax.faces.bean
public class ParentIDNameResolve implements Serializable
{

  // Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver
  @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
  private DataSource dataSource;

  /* 
    Add getter/setter for DataSource
  */
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return this.ds;
  }

  public void DataSource setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  /* Change method signature to non static */
  public int ParentId(int chieldId) throws SQLException
  {

    DataSource ds = getDataSource();

    // your code here

    return ParentId;
  }

  /* Change method signature to non static */
  public String ParentName(int ParentId) throws SQLException
  {

    DataSource ds = getDataSource();

    // your code here

    return ParentName;
  }
}
```

Next you can use it in your code also as injected object and You can be sure that `DataSource` wont' be `null` but if it will be - check is it properly defined as `DataSource` in configuration files.